# Can you restrict ip address on google sign in module?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

So basically i have a website where people can login via google sign in api, i've configured the api purely. The software is made out of php and twig. But i wanted to know if i can restrict sign in from google. Like, 2 people can't log in to the website simultaneously at a moment. Suppose, i have an email logged in via google named email@gmail.com and im gonna log in to the same email from another place with another ip address. Can i restrict that?

Comment: in your code probably but that depends upon your code.

Comment: You must implement that logic in your application. Note: asking for recommendations is off-topic. Instead, create a question with a well-defined programming problem and include your code. Read this guide for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask